# mostrar solo los dias sin sabados, domingos y festivos

Tags: php

saben de una función de como solo mostrar los días del mes actual sin contar sábados, domingos y festivos de país colombia encontre este objeto paara detectar los dias festivos.

```
class festivos 
{

 private $hoy;
 private $festivos;
 private $ano;
 private $pascua_mes;
 private $pascua_dia;


public function festivos($ano='')
{
    $this->hoy=date('d/m/Y');

    if($ano=='')
        $ano=date('Y');

    $this->ano=$ano;

    $this->pascua_mes=date("m", easter_date($this->ano));
    $this->pascua_dia=date("d", easter_date($this->ano));

    $this->festivos[$ano][1][1]   = true;       // Primero de Enero
    $this->festivos[$ano][5][1]   = true;       // Dia del Trabajo 1 de Mayo
    $this->festivos[$ano][7][20]  = true;       // Independencia 20 de Julio
    $this->festivos[$ano][8][7]   = true;       // Batalla de Boyacá 7 de Agosto
    $this->festivos[$ano][12][8]  = true;       // Maria Inmaculada 8 diciembre (religiosa)
    $this->festivos[$ano][12][25] = true;       // Navidad 25 de diciembre

    $this->calcula_emiliani(1, 6);              // Reyes Magos Enero 6
    $this->calcula_emiliani(3, 19);             // San Jose Marzo 19
    $this->calcula_emiliani(6, 29);             // San Pedro y San Pablo Junio 29
    $this->calcula_emiliani(8, 15);             // Asunción Agosto 15
    $this->calcula_emiliani(10, 12);            // Descubrimiento de América Oct 12
    $this->calcula_emiliani(11, 1);             // Todos los santos Nov 1
    $this->calcula_emiliani(11, 11);            // Independencia de Cartagena Nov 11

    //otras fechas calculadas a partir de la pascua.

    $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-3);           //jueves santo
    $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-2);           //viernes santo

    $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(36,true);      //Ascención el Señor pascua
    $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(60,true);      //Corpus Cristi
    $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(68,true);      //Sagrado Corazón

    // otras fechas importantes que no son festivos

    // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-46);       // Miércoles de Ceniza
    // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-46);       // Miércoles de Ceniza
    // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-48);       // Lunes de Carnaval Barranquilla
    // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-47);       // Martes de Carnaval Barranquilla
}
protected function calcula_emiliani($mes_festivo,$dia_festivo) 
{
    // funcion que mueve una fecha diferente a lunes al siguiente lunes en el
    // calendario y se aplica a fechas que estan bajo la ley emiliani
    //global  $y,$dia_festivo,$mes_festivo,$festivo;
    // Extrae el dia de la semana
    // 0 Domingo … 6 Sábado
    $dd = date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$mes_festivo,$dia_festivo,$this->ano));
    switch ($dd) {
    case 0:                                    // Domingo
    $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 1;
    break;
    case 2:                                    // Martes.
    $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 6;
    break;
    case 3:                                    // Miércoles
    $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 5;
    break;
    case 4:                                     // Jueves
    $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 4;
    break;
    case 5:                                     // Viernes
    $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 3;
    break;
    case 6:                                     // Sábado
    $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 2;
    break;
    }
    $mes = date("n", mktime(0,0,0,$mes_festivo,$dia_festivo,$this->ano))+0;
    $dia = date("d", mktime(0,0,0,$mes_festivo,$dia_festivo,$this->ano))+0;
    $this->festivos[$this->ano][$mes][$dia] = true;
}   
protected function otrasFechasCalculadas($cantidadDias=0,$siguienteLunes=false)
{
    $mes_festivo = date("n", mktime(0,0,0,$this->pascua_mes,$this->pascua_dia+$cantidadDias,$this->ano));
    $dia_festivo = date("d", mktime(0,0,0,$this->pascua_mes,$this->pascua_dia+$cantidadDias,$this->ano));

    if ($siguienteLunes)
    {
        $this->calcula_emiliani($mes_festivo, $dia_festivo);
    }   
    else
    {   
        $this->festivos[$this->ano][$mes_festivo+0][$dia_festivo+0] = true;
    }
}   
public function esFestivo($dia,$mes)
{
    //echo (int)$mes;
    if($dia=='' or $mes=='')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($this->festivos[$this->ano][(int)$mes][(int)$dia]))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera simple de poder hacer lo que buscas sería almacenar los días festivos en un array.

Cuando haces eso solo tienes que obtener los días que tiene el mes en curso:

```
$currentMonth = date('t');
```

Ahora toca iterar los días:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $currentMonth; $i += 1) {

}
```

Dentro del bucle solo debes de comprobar si es sábado, domingo o si el día está en el array, si ocurre esto no lo muestras, almacenas etc.
En el if es importante que tengas en cuenta la forma en la que almacenas la fecha en el array, por ejemplo almacenarlo en este formato:

```
01/01/2017
```

Para generar la fecha en el bucle solo tienes que concatenar:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($i.'/'.date("m").'/'.date("Y")));
```

Consiguiendo:

```
$arrayFestivos = array('01/01/2017', '06/01/2017');
$currentMonth = date('t');
for($i = 1; $i <= $currentMonth; $i += 1) {
    if(!in_array(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($i.'/'.date("m").'/'.date("Y"))), $arrayFestivos) && (date('w') != 0 && date('w') != 6)){
        echo $i; //El día no es ni sábado, ni domingo ni festivo.
    }
}
```

He puesto el año pero lo mejor sería no poner para que sirva para todos los años.

Espero haber entendido que es lo que buscas.

¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 3):

Saludos!
Puedes usar la clase de [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) de PHP con la clase [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) para poder crear un [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php) e iterarlo con un foreach.

Aquí inicializamos todas las variables

```
format = 'Y-m-d';
$startDateString = '2017-03-01';
$endDateString = '2017-03-31';
$startDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $startDateString);
$endDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $endDateString);
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
```

Para tomar todas las fechas del mes actual puedes usar el constructor de DateTime para inicializar el primer y último día del mes

```
$startDateTime = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$endDateTime = new DateTime('last day of this month');
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
```

Creamos el DatePeriod con los parametros establecidos

```
$days = new DatePeriod($startDateTime, $dateInterval, $endDateTime);
```

Luego en un array asignamos los días festivos

```
$holidays = [
  '2017-03-20' => true
];
```

Y luego iteramos

```
foreach ($days as $day) {
  // Asignamos un número por cada día de la semana 6 y 7 para sábado y domingo
  $weekDay = $day->format('N');
  // Si es sábado, domingo o festivo no lo imprime
  if ($weekDay !== '6' && 
      $weekDay !== '7' && 
      !isset($holidays[$day->format('Y-m-d')])) {
    print_r($day->format('d-m-Y'));
    echo PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Probado con php 7.0 imprime esto:

01-03-2017
02-03-2017
03-03-2017
06-03-2017
07-03-2017
08-03-2017
09-03-2017
10-03-2017
13-03-2017
14-03-2017
15-03-2017
16-03-2017
17-03-2017
21-03-2017
22-03-2017
23-03-2017
24-03-2017
27-03-2017
28-03-2017
29-03-2017
30-03-2017

Answer (score -1):

Estoy tratando de hacer una función en php que me permita sumar los días dada una fecha pero que no me cuente los fines de semana.
ahora he conseguido que me sume los días y me los muestre tal como quiero es decir que me sume los días pero cada 5 años me sume 3 días, hasta allí todo bien funciona bien me dice cuantos días le corresponde y los años que tiene.
pero ahora me cambiaron todo y me piden que no sean días continuos sino días hábiles y que comience el primer año con 15 dias y por cada año desde la fecha de ingreso me sume un día mas hasta los 15 años y hay si me pare estoy tratando de resolver pero no doy no se si me pueden orientar.

no se si me doy a entender bien.

coloco el código como lo llevo y como me esta funcionando actualmente.

```
$fechaIngreso ='2016-02-01';
$fechaSalida ='2018-10-01';

$fechasalida = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechaSalida));


$fechaIngresoObj = new DateTime($fechaIngreso);
$fechaSalidaObJ = new DateTime($fechaSalida);
$intervalo = $fechaIngresoObj->diff($fechaSalidaObJ);


$anosEnLaInstitucion=$intervalo->y;


if ($anosEnLaInstitucion<5) {
$fechaEsperada = strtotime($fechaSalida."+ 30 days");
$fecha= date("d/m/Y",$fechaEsperada);
}

if (($anosEnLaInstitucion>5) and ($anosEnLaInstitucion<10)) {
$fechaEsperada = strtotime($fechaSalida."+ 33 days");
$fecha= date("d/m/Y",$fechaEsperada);
}

if (($anosEnLaInstitucion>=10) and ($anosEnLaInstitucion<15)) {
$fechaEsperada = strtotime($fechaSalida."+ 36 days");
$fecha= date("d/m/Y",$fechaEsperada);
}

if (($anosEnLaInstitucion>=15) and ($anosEnLaInstitucion<20)) {
$fechaEsperada = strtotime($fechaSalida."+ 39 days");
$fecha= date("d/m/Y",$fechaEsperada);
}

if ($anosEnLaInstitucion> 20) {
$fechaEsperada = strtotime($fechaSalida."+ 42 days");
$fecha= date("d/m/Y",$fechaEsperada);
}
?>

<?php
if ($anosEnLaInstitucion<5) {
$dias ='30';
}

if (($anosEnLaInstitucion>5) and ($anosEnLaInstitucion<10)) {
$dias ='33';
}

if (($anosEnLaInstitucion>=10) and ($anosEnLaInstitucion<15)) {
$dias ='36';
}

if (($anosEnLaInstitucion>=15) and ($anosEnLaInstitucion<20)) {
$dias ='39';
}

if ($anosEnLaInstitucion> 20) {
$dias ='42';
}
?>

Echo 'Le Corresponden '.$dias.' Dias';
Echo '<p>';
Echo 'Debe Regresar el '.$fecha;
```